# How can I use different paths for controllers in AdonisJS?

Tags: adonis.js

I am building a large application using AdonisJS 5.

I want to keep my app folder organized by module, eg:

```
App/
  Modules/
    Users/
      Routes.ts
      Model.ts
      IndexController.ts
      ViewController.ts
```

I can link the routes up by importing the Routes.ts file from start/routes.ts

But how can I register the controllers and their actions for each different module with Adonis?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, you want to keep the `start/routes.ts` file clean to make it readable and scalable.

If this is the question then I have used the following folder structure inside the `App` directory

```
App/
   Controllers/
     UserController.ts
   Middleware/
     Auth.ts
   Models/
     User.ts
   Routes/
     users.ts
```

By doing this I am mapping all the user-related endpoints in `users.ts`. Ex:

```
import Route from '@ioc:Adonis/Core/Route'

Route.group(() => {
  Route.get('/', 'UsersController.index')
  Route.post('/', 'UsersController.create')
  Route.get('/:id', 'UsersController.details')
  Route.put('/:id', 'UsersController.update')
  Route.delete('/:id', 'UsersController.delete')
  Route.post('/login', 'UsersController.login')
})
.prefix('/api/users')
.middleware(['auth'])
```

The same logic goes for other modules and finally imports all the Routes in `App/Routes` from `start/routes.ts`

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by importing your controllers in your routes file:

```js
import Route from '@ioc:Adonis/Core/Route';
import UserIndexController from 'App/Modules/Users/IndexController';

Route.get('/users', async (ctx) => {
  return new UserIndexController().index(ctx);
});
```

If you have many controllers, consider using [lazy loading imports](https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/controllers#lazy-loading) otherwise your routes file can become a bottleneck.